# External monitor doesn't detect MBP with HDMI, detects it with VGA

Tags: macbook-pro, display, usb, hdmi, vga-adapter

I just bought a new **Acer monitor, SA240Y, 24", 1080p**, I have a **Dell DA200 USB Type-C to HDMI/VGA/Ethernet/USB 3.0** converter mini dock. I also have a HDMI cable that I know it works. When I try to connect my MBP (Catalina 10.15.2) with the given VGA cable it works perfectly and detects it right away, but when I try it with the HDMI cable it does not detect it, screen flashes for a second, my mac detects that it is connected to an external monitor but monitor doesn't detect the mac. Any ideas ?

Comment: The [compatibility list](https://www.dell.com/en-us/shop/dell-adapter-usb-c-to-hdmi-vga-ethernet-usb-30-da200/apd/470-abqn/networking?gacd=9694607-1006-5761040-266690904-0&dgc=st&&gclid=CjwKCAiAzNj9BRBDEiwAPsL0d5WIpqGp1y6BgQiOhJ8Wmmnn56jwTAYoHKN9SriC1tblpgGRqvjjGRoC3tcQAvD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds#compatibility_section) for this hub at the Dell site does not have any Apple hardware. Perhaps it just won't work. Also - what model/year of MBP?

Comment: I'm guessing your MBP has USBC ports, so I recommend this hub [from Anker](https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B07ZVKTP53) which I use personally, and professionally in over 70 classrooms to connect to projectors and USB devices and microphones. _Disclaimer:_ No financial or other ties to Amazon.com or Anker.

Comment: Yes acutally it was about the hub I am using, the issue was fixed when I used a different dell hub I got from work, then I was able to change the refresh rate of my monitor down to 60 and now it works on the other small mini hub as well. Appreciate the help.